# Is this algorithm O(n^2) or O(n)

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o

I have 2 list:

- Events list (can have a variable size from 1 element to infinity)
- EventTypesToFilter list (Always fixed/constant size of 1 to max 3 elements)

The algorithm need to filter events by eventType.

The question is,
is algo1 O(n^2) and algo2 O(n)?
or are they both O(n)?

I've also marked in the code the O complexity in various points of the code, please confirm if they are correct **p1.1 , p1.2 , p2.1 , p2.2** ?

I'm basing the final O complexity for each algo based on the highest complexity in each, my assumption is that they are both O(n).

Please add any further observations, also related to sugar code that might seem of a different O complexity.

I assume that the select statement is not running in parallel or any other part of the code is running in parallel.

**There are 2 main list iterations that occur, one loop iterates through a fixed number of elements (EventType list), while the other iterates through a number of elements that can be considered theoretically infinite (Events list).
For this main reason I think that both ALGO1 and ALGO2 are O(n). Please correct me if I'm wrong.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Algo 1 is O(n) or O(n^2)?
            var resp1 = FilterEventsAlgo1(GetEvents(), GetEventTypesToFilter());
            //Algo 2 is O(n) or O(n^2)?
            var resp2 = FilterEventsAlgo2(GetEvents(), GetEventTypesToFilter());
        }

        static List<EventResponse> FilterEventsAlgo1(List<Event> events, List<EventType> eventTypesToFilter)
        {
            var filteredEvents = new List<EventResponse>();
            //p1.1 is O(n)?
            foreach (Event ev in events)
            {
                //p1.2 is O(1)?
                if (eventTypesToFilter.Any(x => x == ev.EventType))
                {
                    filteredEvents.Add(new EventResponse());
                }
            }
            return filteredEvents;
        }

        static List<EventResponse> FilterEventsAlgo2(List<Event> events, List<EventType> eventTypesToFilter)
        {
            //p2.1 is O(1)?
            events.RemoveAll(x => !eventTypesToFilter.Contains(x.EventType));
            //p2.2 is O(n)?
            var filteredEvents = events.Select(x => new EventResponse()).ToList();

            return filteredEvents;
        }

        static List<Event> GetEvents()
        {
            //... Theretically the number of elements CAN VARY TO A GREATER NUMBER up to infinity
            List<Event> Events = new List<Event> {
                new Event(EventType.Type1),
                new Event(EventType.Type2),
                new Event(EventType.Type3),
                new Event(EventType.Type3),
                new Event(EventType.Type3)
            };
            return Events;
        }

        static List<EventType> GetEventTypesToFilter()
        {
            //... The number of elements in this list is always limited to max 3, can be seen as a constant number of elements
            List<EventType> EventTypesToFilter = new List<EventType> {
                EventType.Type1,
                EventType.Type2,
            };
            return EventTypesToFilter;
        }

    }

    class Event
    {
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }
        public Event(EventType eventType)
        {
            this.EventType = eventType;
        }
    }

    class EventResponse
    {

    }


   
    enum EventType
    {
        Type1,
        Type2,
        Type3
    }
}
```

Comment: What performance tests have you run? How do those tests change as you increase the input size? What have you tried? As it stands, this question is better suited to the code review stackoverflow. Given that you have nested loops, it's a safe bet that it's O(n^2) or more.

Comment: @RichardBarker just pure theory, just checking if they both are O(n) and ignoring the steepness of O(n)

Comment: @RichardBarker to be honest this was today's argument, lasting 4 hours for a silly Pull Request. lol

Comment: Run performance tests then. Increase input size by orders of magnitude a couple of times and then graph the time vs size. you'll see either linear or exponential results.

Comment: @RichardBarker please consider that 1 loop is always iterating the same number (constant) of elements (this should be O(n), please confirm?). While the other loop , the list of elements can be indefinitely big.

Comment: Both algos are semantically the same. But they both still use nested loops regardless of one loop having a constant number of iterations, the second loops creates the exponential. At least, that's my understanding. It may be flawed. It could be O(x•y) or O(x^y)

Comment: ```p1.2 is O(1)?``` no, the Any has to iterate the list, so O(n), or O(m) for the purposes of the overall O(n*m). Meaning for the outer loop, it has a max constant cost independent of n

Comment: as an aside, if the filters are reasonably long, it would be better as a HashSet

Comment: @KeithNicholas yep, just corrected those 2 points p1.2 and p2.1 both are O(n). Thanks

Comment: Both of them are obviously O(1) - the number of possible value of types is limited (you can only have enum of `long` type at most and number of elements in an array is limited - max size must be under 2GB) :)... But seriously why don't you simply write obviously reasonable code with `HashSet<EventTypesToFilter>` and be done with it?

Comment: @KeithNicholas sorry but p1.2 and p2.1 are both O(1), since in both cases the loop/list iteration is always max 3, that can be considered a constant of 1, 2 or 3.
As I mentioned EventTypesToFilter can have max 3 distinct items.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes both p1.2 and p2.1 are O(1)

Comment: you are changing this question too much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those algorithms are very similar, and both have the same complexity.

If you wanted to state that complexity in a meaningful way, then you would say it's O(events.size() * eventTypesToFilter.size()), or O(n * m), where n and m are those sizes.

If you really must state it in terms of total input size only, then it would be O(n<sup>2</sup>)... but really you wouldn't do that.  If you say O(n * m), then the caller knows that if he passes you a fixed-size event type list, then his algorithm can be O(n), and he gets some idea of how the cost of calling your code would increase as that 'fixed' size increases.

Comment: Have take in consideration my 2 initial statements? Events list (can have a variable size from 1 element to infinity), EventType list (Always fixed size of 3 elements)

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the algorithms you wrote, which each take two lists and work just fine no matter how big the second list is.   No matter, though, it's still much better to say O(n * m), and everyone will understand that that means O(n) if m is bounded.  It's important to think about *why* you would want to state your algorithm's complexity in the first place.  It's about *communicating* an understanding of its costs.

Comment: but would you say that definitely none of them are O(n^2)?

Comment: No, that's the sort of thing you would say if you were trying to win a silly argument on a PR :)

Comment: I should add that the *appropriate* thing to say on a PR is "well, neither of these algorithms is significantly faster than the other, " + (isCodeOwner(commenter) ? "but it's your code, so OK" : "so I will leave it the way it is")

Comment: you mean No, in the sense that both are not O(n^2) ?
:-)

Comment: Sure!  You can say that they are both O(n), where n is the product of the two list sizes.

Answer (score 2):

They are both O(n) because `GetEventTypesToFilter` has a constant number of elements. If `GetEventTypesToFilter` also grew with problem size then both algorithms would be O(n^2) or O(n * m).

For each event in `GetEvents` you do a constant amount of work and loop over `GetEvents` a constant number of times (once for algorithm one, twice for algorithm two).

Comment: The text says that the event type list is of constant size, but the algorithms implemented don't assume that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Sure, but it is totally reasonable to say an algorithm has different complexity under different parameter restrictions. In this case, it was stated that the filter list is constant - with that assumption the algorithm has linear complexity.

Comment: Yes, the filter list is constant, while the Events list can be of any size. Using limit theory as size -> infinity or as Events list size tends to infinity